# override setTextFormat as3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I've written some code that uses setTextFormat to apply formatting to textFields.  I need to change it now so if a textfield has a particular title it adds to the formatting (capitalising it).

Theres several workarounds I could use but ideally I would like to either create an override for the setTextFormat or textFormat classes that checks the name of the textfield and if it's a particular name before applying all the other specified formatting capitalises it.  I know how to override a setter such as (width or height) but can't find any info on overriding a specific property.

Can anyone give me any pointers please?

Answer (score 0):

[[Edit]]

Did not realize the question was in reference to AS2.  The answer below is AS3.

---

I would suggest extending the TextField object and overriding the set defaultTextFormat method.

```
import flash.text.TextField;
import flash.text.TextFormat;

class MyTextField extends TextField
{

    public function MyTextField()
    {
        super();
    }

    override public function set defaultTextFormat(value:TextFormat):void
    {
        super.defaultTextFormat = value;
    }

}
```

Best of luck!

Comment: Hi, the question was with reference to AS3.  Thanks for that, I was hoping to solve this without creating a textfield subclass though.

Answer (score 0):

```
 public class MyField extends TextField {
     public function MyField() {
        super();
     }
     override public function setTextFormat(format:TextFormat):void {
          if (this.name == "someName") {
            this.capitalize();
          }
          super.setTextFormat(format);
     }
     private function capitalize():void
     {
         //code to capitalize text
     }

 }
```

Comment: Thanks for that, again I was hoping to do so without creating a specific text subclass.  Guess it's not possible.

Comment: You can write a function in your document class or some utility class to implement this functionality, but still you'd have to change all the code `textField.setTextFormat(format)` to something like `setTextFormat(textField, format)`. You cannot override default setTextFormat behaviour without extending `TextField` class and converting all you textFields to that subclass.